# Versioning php files locally

Tags: php, git, version-control, versioning

So I have Laravel project, it also has repo on Bitbucket etc., but what could I do if **I want to use some local file versioning**?

I'd want not only to have multiple files with versions, but also a possibility to somehow rollback the file. So basically I need a local repo.

Is there some kind of **local GitHub?** Or what else could be used in this situation? Preferably **php-based**, so I could, for example, make `php artisan` commands that would do something with these versioned files.

Would highly appreciate any possible help!

Comment: Why you dont just install git ? Multi-OS, simple & fast, doing exactly what you want to do https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: You can create/clone a git repo locally and then commit-rollback easily - it will all be stored on your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to use GIT Branching. You can work in a branch and then merge it into the trunk before pushing your trunk changes to the server

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/

Comment: Peter thanks for the link. That tutorial looks nice and simple to follow.

Comment: If you are using github then your local files are already a GIT repository. So it's a no-brainer decision :)

Answer (score 0):

Like the others, I recommend `git`. It took me a couple of hours of dedicated effort to learn the basics, but now that I use it, I don't know how I ever coded without it and I'm still just a beginner at it! Git fits your requirements to perfection, and as a bonus it is not limited to `.php` files but add any file in your project to version control.

Here is the simplest way to get started that I've found: https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1